# Clearing Issue Navigator in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

While doing a big rework of my code, I accidentally built the project. Naturally, there was a whole bunch of errors. So now I have all these annoying error messages in my code.

How do I clear the Issue Navigator and get rid of them?

Comment: what are the errors? your question is not cleared at all..!! what rework and the errors and what is the issue regarding navigator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>Product|Clean</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> cleans the code.

Also you can visit the organiser and remove the build logs

Comment: This worked for me for a while, but now after Product|Clean its still showing the issues. Help!!!!